# How to turn rows of a dataframe into feature vectors?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

So, I have a dataframe each rows of which represent some low-level user activity on a computer associated with a higher-level business process activity. The high-level business process activity is comprised of sequences of such low-level activities represented by each row. The data frame looks like this:
[image]

So, it is a sequence classification problem where each sequence is identified by the case ID and each row represents the data point of the sequences. I need to train a model to predict the Business Process Activity that each sequence represents.

For this I need to transform each row of the dataframe into a feature vector but the problem is that the columns of the dataframe contain different information each row and some the data is numerical and some are textual (For example: the content inside the word document). I need to use of all the data for training. How do I convert these rows into feature vectors for training?

Comment: For textual data, check bag of words which is the simplest form of text representation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I need to create each row into a feature vector. Each column of the row represent different things. For example, there is a column which stores the body of the text inside the Microsoft Word document. I can use "bag of words" for that but then there is another column which represents the editing time of the document, etc which has a completely different contextual meaning. So, how do I convert such a row of data into a feature vector?

Comment: Hi user8525740, I interested to know if you have found the solution? do you mind to share to help who are struggling on this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With textual data what you are looking for in called embedding. If you only have a few unique values a text field takes, then one hot encoding (for example `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`). For a more elaborate sequences (with more than 100k different values), you may want to look into sequence encoding. One of the ways is for example to use embedding provided by google (see  for example https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) for every word, which yields vectors for every word in a text sequence. Afterwards, for every text sequence, vectors are averaged, which gives a representation of an entire sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I need to create each row into a feature vector. Each row represents different low-level activity and each column of the row represent different things describing the activity. For example, there is a column which stores the body of the text inside the Microsoft Word document and another column which represents the editing time of the document. For a different activity, those columns might be different. The columns have completely different contextual meaning. So, how do I convert such a row of data into a feature vector?

Comment: My pleasure. Essentially you can process this mixed type data by column. If you have a column with text values and there are few unique values, you can denote each of them as a vector of different kinds. Start with OneHotEncoder (https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd). Once you understand that check out LabelBinarizer. If your column has lots of unique values, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302280/creating-sequence-vector-from-text-in-python/38306607.

Comment: If you need compact vectors with floating point numbers (what I originally suggested) consider https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-word-embedding-using-word2vec/ . I would suggest you to read about OneHotEncoder first to wrap your head around the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples, one using `labelencoder` and one using `onehotencoder`.

LE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder# creating initial dataframe
bridge_types = ('Arch','Beam','Truss','Cantilever','Tied Arch','Suspension','Cable')
bridge_df = pd.DataFrame(bridge_types, columns=['Bridge_Types'])# creating instance of labelencoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()# Assigning numerical values and storing in another column
bridge_df['Bridge_Types_Cat'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(bridge_df['Bridge_Types'])
bridge_df
```

Result:

```
  Bridge_Types  Bridge_Types_Cat
0         Arch                 0
1         Beam                 1
2        Truss                 6
3   Cantilever                 3
4    Tied Arch                 5
5   Suspension                 4
6        Cable                 2
```

OHE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder# creating instance of one-hot-encoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')# passing bridge-types-cat column (label encoded values of bridge_types)
enc_df = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(bridge_df[['Bridge_Types_Cat']]).toarray())# merge with main df bridge_df on key values
bridge_df = bridge_df.join(enc_df)
bridge_df
```

Result:

```
  Bridge_Types  Bridge_Types_Cat    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0         Arch                 0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1         Beam                 1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2        Truss                 6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
3   Cantilever                 3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4    Tied Arch                 5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
5   Suspension                 4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
6        Cable                 2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Notice: make sure you do this ony on columns that are actual labels, and not on ones that are...let's say IDs or dates, or anything along these lines.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I need to create each row into a feature vector. Each row represents different low-level activity and each column of the row represent different things describing the activity. For example, there is a column which stores the body of the text inside the Microsoft Word document and another column which represents the editing time of the document. For a different activity, those columns might be different. The columns have completely different contextual meaning. So, how do I convert such a row of data into a feature vector?